# JavaScript recursion find node return null

Tags: javascript, recursion, null

How can I get the matching node?
I always get null return although the alert of the matching node is displayed.

There must be a sulution for this with recursion.

I just want to find for an ID the corresponding node element.
Is this even possible via jQuery for a JSON object?

```js
function getNode(processingNode, searchNodeId) {
  if(processingNode.tags == searchNodeId) {
    alert("match!");
    return processingNode;
  }
  else {
    var result = null;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < processingNode.nodes.length; i++) {
      result = getNode(processingNode.nodes[i], searchNodeId);
    }
    
    return result;
  }
}

var nodes = [{
  "tags": "1",
  "text": "BG",
  "nodes": [{
    "tags": "11",
    "text": "DLT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "12",
    "text": "HBM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "13",
    "text": "MBM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "14",
    "text": "RT",
    "nodes": [{
      "tags": "141",
      "text": "FSP",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "142",
      "text": "HHR",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "143",
      "text": "KHR",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "144",
      "text": "KM",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "145",
      "text": "Sauger",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "146",
      "text": "SM",
      "nodes": []
    }]
  }, {
    "tags": "2",
    "text": "ST",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "3",
    "text": "WHT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "4",
    "text": "ZDLT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "5",
    "text": "ZHBM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "6",
    "text": "ZMM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "7",
    "text": "ZRT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "8",
    "text": "ZST",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "9",
    "text": "ZHT",
    "nodes": []
  }]}
]

$(function() {
  var matchingNode = getNode(nodes[0], 142);
  alert(matchingNode);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just a tip: you'd be wise not to use names of common properties in your comments/data structures. For instance, you use the term ID and Tags interchangeably in your question. `id` and `tagName` are already frequently utilized, assigned properties on Node objects.It could and  absolutely will lead to confusion when someone other than you is trying to understand your code.

Comment: I understand you're probably new to all of this so I'll point out that some of the mistakes you're making are only happening because there are traps in imperative style. Please review my answer to see how it's possible to escape painful for-loops, variable (re)assignments, and single-branch if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Your `for` loop keeps looping even after a match is found, so `result` will be overridden by `null` if the other elements (the one after the matched one) didn't match the given ID.

For example, if at the 5<sup>th</sup> iteration we got a result back, then we should stop the loop and return. Instead, your code, keeps looking, so if the last iteration doesn't match, `result` will be assigned the value `null` (overriding the previous value at the 5<sup>th</sup> iteration). Conclusion: your code works only if the last item of an array matches the ID (in that case the loop will stop anyway).

**Suggested fix:**

Change the loop to something like this:

```
var result = null;
for(var i = 0; i < processingNode.nodes.length; i++) {
    result = getNode(processingNode.nodes[i], searchNodeId);
    if(result) {            // if we got a result
         return result;     // then return immediately and stop looping
    }
}
return result;              // keep this in case we don't find anything (or remove it as undefined will be returned implicitly), or change to simply 'return null;'
```

**Working example:**

```js
function getNode(processingNode, searchNodeId) {
  if(processingNode.tags == searchNodeId) {
    alert("match!");
    return processingNode;
  }
  else {
    var result = null;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < processingNode.nodes.length; i++) {
      result = getNode(processingNode.nodes[i], searchNodeId);
      if(result) return result;
    }
    
    return result;
  }
}

var nodes = [{
  "tags": "1",
  "text": "BG",
  "nodes": [{
    "tags": "11",
    "text": "DLT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "12",
    "text": "HBM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "13",
    "text": "MBM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "14",
    "text": "RT",
    "nodes": [{
      "tags": "141",
      "text": "FSP",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "142",
      "text": "HHR",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "143",
      "text": "KHR",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "144",
      "text": "KM",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "145",
      "text": "Sauger",
      "nodes": []
    }, {
      "tags": "146",
      "text": "SM",
      "nodes": []
    }]
  }, {
    "tags": "2",
    "text": "ST",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "3",
    "text": "WHT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "4",
    "text": "ZDLT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "5",
    "text": "ZHBM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "6",
    "text": "ZMM",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "7",
    "text": "ZRT",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "8",
    "text": "ZST",
    "nodes": []
  }, {
    "tags": "9",
    "text": "ZHT",
    "nodes": []
  }]}
]

$(function() {
  var matchingNode = getNode(nodes[0], 142);
  alert(matchingNode);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Square 1**

First, there's no such thing as a *"JSON Object"* – JSON is always a string. What you have in your program is a *JavaScript Object*. Writing out each node's data like this by-hand using JavaScript object literal syntax is a bit crude, so we'll start by making a constructor function for our nodes instead

```
// Node :: (String, String, [Node]) -> Node
const Node = (tags, text, nodes = []) =>
  ({ tags, text, nodes })
```

Now we write our data like this

```
const tree = 
  Node ("1", "BG",
   [ Node ("11", "DLT")
   , Node ("12", "HBM")
   , Node ("13", "MBM")
   // ...
   ] )
```

Searching a tree for a particular node is an essential operation, but limiting our search to a specific field (ie `tags`) is an arbitrary limitation – let's make our search function generic so that we can search for whatever we want

```
// searchTree :: ((Node -> Boolean), Node, Int) -> Node?
const searchTree = (f, node, cursor = 0) =>
  cursor === node.nodes.length
    ? f (node)
      ? node
      : null
    : searchTree (f, node.nodes [cursor]) || searchTree (f, node, cursor + 1)
```

With a generic search function in place, we can implement our search-by-tags function easily

```
// getNodeByTags :: (Node, String) -> Node?
const getNodeByTags = (node, tags) =>
  searchTree (n => n.tags === tags, node)
```

Here's a complete demo to show it all working - the last line demonstrates the versatility of implementation choice

```js
const Node = (tags, text, nodes = []) =>
  ({ tags, text, nodes })
  
const searchTree = (f, node, cursor = 0) =>
  cursor === node.nodes.length
    ? f (node)
      ? node
      : null
    : searchTree (f, node.nodes [cursor]) || searchTree (f, node, cursor + 1)

const getNodeByTags = (node, tags) =>
  searchTree (node => node.tags === tags, node)

const tree =
  Node ("0", "ROOT",
    [ Node ("1", "BG",
      [ Node ("11", "DLT")
      , Node ("12", "HBM")
      , Node ("13", "MBM")
      , Node ("14", "RT",
        [ Node ("141", "FSP")
        , Node ("142", "HHR")
        , Node ("143", "KHR")
        , Node ("144", "KM")
        , Node ("145", "Sauger")
        , Node ("146", "Sm")
        ] )
      ] )
    , Node ("2", "ST")
    , Node ("3", "WHT")
    , Node ("4", "ZDLT")
    , Node ("5", "ZHBM")
    , Node ("6", "ZMM")
    ] )

console.log (getNodeByTags (tree, "142"))
// { tags: '142', text: 'HHR', nodes: [] }

console.log (getNodeByTags (tree, "999"))
// null

console.log (searchTree (n => n.text === "ZDLT", tree))
// { tags: '4', text: 'ZDLT', nodes: [] }
```

What to read next: [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)